# Is there any CLI way to show information about Glassfish JDBC connection pool?

Tags: glassfish-3, asadmin

The only relevant command that I found is:

> NAME
>        list-jdbc-connection-pools - lists all JDBC connection pools
>
> EXAMPLES
>        This example lists the existing JDBC connection pools.
>
> ```
>    asadmin> list-jdbc-connection-pools
>    sample_derby_pool
>    __TimerPool
>    Command list-jdbc-connection-pools executed successfully.
> ```

What I want is to display the information about particular connection pool. Such as:

> asadmin desc-jdbc-connection-pool sample_derby_pool
>
> name: sample_derby_pool
>   databaseName: oracle
>   portNumber: 1521
>   serverName: test
>   user: testUser
>   ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running:

*asadmin get * | more*

The above command will display **all** GlassFish attributes.  Pipe it to grep to get just the pool properties you are interested in:

*asadmin get * | grep TimerPool*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After googling around, I'd thought that the possible solution would be to [extend asadmin utility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2415/ghmza.html) which doesn't seem too hard.

Comment: Yeah, you could do that but it seems a bit overkill unless there are pretty specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks John. Also useful: `asadmin get domain.resources.jdbc-connection-pool.POOLNAME.\*`